# Limits problem (unable to solve further)

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Struggling to solve this problem,

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} +\dots+ \frac{1}{6n}\right)$

My approach:

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} +...+ \frac{1}{6n}\right)$

= $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}(x^{n-1} + x^{n} + x^{n-2}+...+ x^{6n-1}) dx$

= $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{n-1} \cdot \frac{x^{5n+1} - 1}{x-1}\right)dx$

got stuck here and don't know how to solve it further (other approaches which are simpler would also help)

Comment: Should there be $x$ in the limit? Also what about the limits of integration?

Comment: @SineoftheTime I have corrected it now, sorry!

Comment: @ArunMadhav no need to be sorry, I'll delete my comment ;)

Comment: What is  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$, ...? From here you can calculate the limit of the sum.

Comment: How does it help @bayes2021 ?

Comment: @mowzorn Well each term has limit $0$ and since the sum is finite this would also be the limit of the sum.

Comment: No, because in each 'step' the number of terms in the sum changes.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry.

Comment: There's no problem :)

Comment: `Limit[Sum[1/i, {i, n, 6*n}], n -> Infinity]` $\log (6)$

Comment: You should be able to use estimates (inequalities of areas) from the graph of $y=1/x$ to answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also can use Riemann-sums:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots + \frac{1}{6n}\right)
$$
$$
=
\left(1+\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+2}+\dots + \frac{n}{n+ (5n-1)}\right)\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{6n}
$$
$$
=\left(1+\frac{1}{1+1/n}+\frac{1}{1+2/n}+\dots + \frac{1}{1+(5n-1)/n}\right)\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{6n}
$$
$$
\to \int_0^5\frac{1}{1+x}dx + 0 = \ln(6) \quad (n \to \infty).
$$

Edit: On the interval $[0,5]$ we consider the partition
$$
x_k=\frac{k}{n} \quad (k=0, \dots, 5n),
$$
and the function $f(x)=1/(1+x)$. Choosing the left boundary point on each interval $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ we get the Riemann-sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{5n-1} f(x_k) (x_{k+1}-x_k) = \sum_{k=0}^{5n-1} \frac{1}{1+k/n} \cdot \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Now it is known that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{5n-1} f(x_k) (x_{k+1}-x_k) \to \int_0^5 f(x) dx \quad (n \to \infty);
$$
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum, for example.

Comment: your approach is similar to the solution provided in which I was unable to understand how they took the decision to go from summation(your 3rd step) to integration(4th step), could you explain what is the intuition for converting a summation into integration in general?

Comment: I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I will use the fact that the sequence
$$x_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n$$
has a limit $\gamma = 0.577...$ (known as Euler–Mascheroni constant). Let's denote
$$a_n = \frac{1}{n}+\ldots+\frac{1}{6n}.$$
We can see that
$$x_{6n}-x_{n-1}=a_n-\ln(6n)+\ln(n-1) = a_n -\ln\left(\frac{6n}{n-1}\right).$$
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x_{6n}-x_{n-1}+\ln\left(\frac{6n}{n-1}\right)\right) = \gamma-\gamma+\ln6 = \ln 6.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let define $\displaystyle H_n=1+\frac {1}{2}+ \frac {1}{3}...+\frac {1}{n}
 $ more precisely is the sum up to n $H_n=\sum_{k=0}^n=\frac {1}{k}$.

Using Euler-Maclaurin formula $\displaystyle H_n=ln(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\epsilon_n$ where $\gamma\approx0.5772...$and $0\le\epsilon_n\le\frac{1}{8n^2}$

$\displaystyle H_{6n}=ln(6n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{6n}-\epsilon_{6n}$

Noting that your expression is equal to:

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} +\dots+ \frac{1}{6n}\right)$=

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} H_{6n}-H_n$ =
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ ($ln(6n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{6n}-\epsilon_{6n}-(ln(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\epsilon_n)$)=

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ ($ln(6)+ln(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{6n}-\epsilon_{6n}-ln(n)-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}+\epsilon_n$)= $ln(6)$.

Answer (score 4):

This method uses neither the Euler-Mascheroni constant, nor Riemann sums. Rather, it uses bounds from the graph of $\ f(x) = \frac{1}{x},\ $ using the fact that $\ f\ $ is decreasing towards $\ 0.$

Whenever $\ k\geq i\geq 1,\ $ we have:

$$\int_{x=i+1}^{x=k+1} \frac{1}{x} dx \leq \sum_{j=i+1}^{j=k} \frac{1}{j} \leq \int_{x=i}^{x=k} \frac{1}{x} dx $$

$$ \implies \ln(k+1) - \ln(i+1) \leq \sum_{j=i+1}^{j=k} \frac{1}{j} \leq \ln(k) - \ln(i). \qquad (1) $$

If $\ n\ $ is large enough, we can substitute $\ k=6n\ $ and $\ k=n-1\ $ into $\ (1)\ $ giving, respectively:

$$ \ln(6n+1) - \ln(i+1) \leq \sum_{j=i+1}^{j=6n} \frac{1}{j} \leq \ln(6n) - \ln(i) \qquad (2) $$

and

$$ \ln(n) - \ln(i+1) \leq \sum_{j=i+1}^{j=n-1} \frac{1}{j} \leq \ln(n-1) - \ln(i). \qquad (3) $$

$(2),\ (3)\implies$

$$\ln\left(\frac{6n+1}{n-1}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{i}{i+1}\right) \leq \sum_{j=n}^{j=6n} \frac{1}{j} \leq \ln\left(\frac{6n}{n}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{i+1}{i}\right). \qquad (4) $$

Taking limits in $\ (4),\ $ first as $\ n\to\infty,\ $ then as $\ i\to\infty,\ $ we get:

$$\ln 6 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=n}^{j=6n} \frac{1}{j} \leq \ln6. $$

Comment: I think in the lower bound of summation the integral in equation (1) should be $i+2$ to $k+1$ or any other value to the right of $i+1$ ?

Comment: @ArunMadhav I'm confident that $(1)$ is correct: it uses the fact that $f(x)=1/x$ is decreasing towards $0.$ I've drawn a a sketch and I don't see anything wrong with my sketch, so can you explain what you think is wrong about $(1)$ (or the integral inequality above $(1)$)?

Comment: as our summation is from $i+1$ to $k$ and as $f(x)$ is a decreasing function but always greater than $0$ so $i+1$ to $k+1$ would be greater than the summation from $i+1$ to $k$ as we are covering more area...that's why I got that doubt, am I making a mistake? if the summation was from $i$ to $k$ then I totally agree that the integral from $i+1$ to $k$ will be a lower bound.

Comment: You say: "(the integral from) $i+1$ to $k+1$ would be greater than the sum from $i+1$ to $k$", but this is not true. As an example, let's look at the area under the graph $\ f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\ $ between $\ x=1\ $ and $\ x=2.\ $ Using the fact that $\ \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{1}\ \forall x\in [1,2],\ $ it follows that $ \int_{x=1}^{x=2}\frac{1}{x} dx \leq 1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1}\right) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{j=1} \frac{1}{j}.\ $ Notice that just because the difference between the integration limits is $\ 1\ $ and the difference between the summation limits is zero does not mean the...

Comment: ... summation is less than the integral. Your misconception is thinking that $\ \sum_{a}^{b} g(z)\ $ has $\ (b-a)\ $ terms, but actually, it has $\ (b-a+1)\ $ terms. I'll try to edit my answer if I get time later tonight to include a diagram for integral inequality $(1)$ which hopefully better illuminates where the inequality comes from.

Comment: you don't need to edit it...actually  I had come across this approach in appendex of cormen text book...it would be my misconception I'll look into it again need some time...thanks alot!